# Vert.x publish HttpServerRequest to other module

Tags: http, vert.x

if i receive a HttpServerRequest in a Handler, is it somehow possible to publish the request?

I want to implement a small demo website with an index.html and an unknown number of sub sites. At first there should be a main vert.x module, which starts the HttpServer. In this main module it should be possible to add other dependent modules. I will call them submodules now. I don't know how many submodules i will have later, but each submodule should contain the logic to handle the http response for a specific URL (the sub html files). I guess i have to do the same for the WebSocketHandler...

A small example of the code inside the start():

```
    //My Main Module:
    vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(new Handler<HttpServerRequest>() {
        public void handle(HttpServerRequest req) {
            vertx.eventBus().publish("HTTP_REQUEST_CONSTANT", req);
        }
    }).listen(8080);


    // My submodule 1
    vertx.eventBus().registerHandler("HTTP_REQUEST_CONSTANT", new Handler<HttpServerRequest>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpServerRequest req) {
            if (req.uri().equals("/")) {
                req.response();
            }
        }
    });

    // Other submodules which handles other URLs
```

Or any other solutions? I just don't wanna have the logic for sub sites in the main module.

Edit: Or could i call the vertx.createHttpServer() method in each submodule?

Comment: Played with this a bit but didn't find a self contained way.  "self contained" meaning, as opposed to an external web proxy (apache etc) which maps different paths to modules each running their own http listener on different ports. Not convenient for development, though. Good question.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar Vert.x based application and I ended up doing the following:
I have a `HttpServerVerticle` that is started from the `MainVerticle`. There I created an `HttpServer` with several matchers. Each matcher receives a request and forwards it to a dedicated verticle through the`EventBus`. Upon getting the response from a dedicated verticle it writes the answer to the response.
Here is a code snippet:

```
RouteMatcher restMatcher = new RouteMatcher();
EventBus eventBus = vertx.eventBus();
HttpServer httpServer = vertx.createHttpServer();

restMatcher.post("/your/url",
            r -> {
                r.bodyHandler(requestBody -> {
                    final int length = requestBody.length();
                    if(length == 0) {
                        //return bad request
                        r.response().setStatusCode(HttpResponseStatus.BAD_REQUEST.code());
                        r.response().end();
                        return;
                    }

                    eventBus.send("your.address.here",
                            requestBody.getString(0, length),
                            new Handler<Message<JsonObject>>(){
                                @Override
                                public void handle(Message<JsonObject> message) {
                                    //return the response from the other verticle
                                    r.response().setStatusCode(HttpResponseStatus.OK.code());
                                    if (message.body() != null) {
                                        r.response().end(message.body().toString());
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        r.response().end();
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                });
            });

httpServer.requestHandler(restMatcher);
httpServer.listen(yourPort,yourHost);
```

In the dedicated verticle you register a listener to the address:

```
 vertx.eventBus().registerHandler("your.address.here", this::yourHandlerMethod);
```

The handler method would look something like the following:

```
protected void yourHandlerMethod(Message<String> message){
    // do your magic, produce an answer
    message.reply(answer);
}
```

This way you separate your logic from your HTTP mappings and can have different pieces of logic in separate verticles using multiple event bus addresses.

Hope this helps.